# GSTREAMER access video before an event

Tags: gstreamer, buffering

I have a SW that performs some video analysis as soon as an event (alarm) happens.

Since I have not enough space on my embedded board, I should start recording the video only when an alarm happens; 
The algorithm works on a video stored offline (it is not a real time algorithm, so the video should be stored, it doesn't suffice to attach to video stream).

At present time I'm able to attach to video and to store it as soon as I detect the alarm condition. 
However I would like to analyze the data 10 seconds before the event happens.
Is it possible to pre-record up to 10 seconds as a FIFO queue, without storing the whole stream on disk?

I found something similar to my requirements here:

https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php/GStreamer_pre-record_element#Video_pre-recording_example

but I would like to know if there is some way I can have the same result, without using the ridgerun tool.
Best regards
Giovanni

Comment: 1. How about having a `queue` with enough size to hold data for 10 seconds? 2. Or a temporary `sink/ring buffer`(which can hold data for 10 seconds), which is being fed with data continuously. This `sink`, later becomes the `source` when the alarm is detected, and you mux it with the actual `source` to record it finally.

Comment: Well thank you for your hint. 
I should further elaborate the idea you suggested. 
Your first idea is to save 10 video seconds on a queue and when the alarm happens, save the video on another file. Then "concatenating" the video, I should be able to work on a well formed video.
Is it right? Do you have any link to understand how to approach the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I mixed up my ideas, and both of them seem to be the similar. 
What I suggest is the following :

1. Have an element that behaves like ringbuffer, though which you can stream backwards in time. A good example to try out might be the èlement `queue`. Have a look at [time-shift buffering](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/advanced/buffering.html#timeshift-buffering).
2. Then store the contents to a file on alarm, and use another pipeline that read from it. For eg. use `tee` or `output-selector`.

   ```
                             | -> ring-buffer
   src -> output-selector -> |   
                             |-> (on alarm) -> ringbuffer + live-src -> file-sink
   ```

From your question, I understand that your `src` might be a live camera, and hence doing this can be tricky. Probably you might have to implement your own plugin as done by the RidgeRun team, otherwise this solution is more of a hack rather than a meaningful solution. Sadly there aren't many references for such a solution, you might have to try it out.

Comment: Thank you for your really useful help. I will work on this topic in the next few weeks. Best regards